# What version of Angular material should be used for angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I started learning angular 2. I am trying to use angular material in my sample application. I have installed angular material using this command "**npm install --save @angular/material**". I understood that this installed me the latest version of angular material which will be supported by angular 4 but not angular 2. What version of angular material should I use? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Release notes](https://github.com/angular/material2/releases) Angular 4 is introduced in 2.0.0-beta.3, so you should be good with 2.0.0-beta.2 in your sample application.

Comment: Is it fine if I replace the version in package.json file of my app or should I replace it even in node_modules/@angular/material/package.json also?

I did both in both ways but It didn't work for me still I face the same problem.

Comment: Run below where you have your project package.json. This will update your packgae.json and install this version as well.
npm install @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.3 --save --save-exact